# How is $S_n$ not simple for $n \geq 3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I know the only normal subgroups of $S_n, n \geq 3$, are itself and the trivial subgroup. But why is this the case?

Answer (score 10):

This is not true. $A_n$ is normal in $S_n$ for all $n \geq 3$.

Comment: Then you need to prove that $A_n$ is normal in $S_n$. How would you go about doing that? (Hint: think about the parity of a permutation in $A_n$ before and after conjugation by an element in $S_n$)

Comment: Proving normalacy is just showing the left and right cosets are equal. So I would just show $sA_n=A_ns$  $\forall s \in S_n$

Comment: In this particular case, it might be easier to show that $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$, $\tau \in A_n$ is still an even permutation...

Comment: Or one could observe that $A_{n}$ has index $2$ in $S_{n}$, hence must be normal.

Comment: @AWertheim That works too. It seemed like a fairly simple question though, so I wasn't sure that atherton had covered that in class yet.

Comment: @Johanna indeed, your method works quite nicely. Just offering another possible solution :)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Johanna's answer, one way to look at it is to look at the set:

$$\left\{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n\mid \sum x_i=1\text{ and } \forall i\, x_i\geq 0\right\}$$

This is a simplex in $n-1$ dimensions, and $S_n$ acts on it in an obvious way - permuting the $x_i$. The action in some cases is orientation preserving, and in other cases, orientation inverting.

We can send orientation preserving maps to $+1$ and orientation-inverting maps to $-1$ and we get a group homomorphism, whose kernel is $A_n$. So $A_n$ represents the orientation-preserving maps, and is a normal subgroup.